# iOS Enterprise Developer Account and Public Betas?

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

I'm seeing more and more developers releasing public beta builds of their apps under an Enterprise developer account. Last I read, the Enterprise TOS only allows for releasing the app in-house to employees only. Does Apple now officially condone using Enterprise accounts for public betas, or are these developers just hoping Apple doesn't sue them for violation of contract?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the legal wording actually insinuates members of your organization. I know of one case where a member-owned organization has released public betas of apps and was deemed to be within the constraints of the contract. IANAL; YMMV